# Join and concat rows based on other row values

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to combine tables based on Issue and User columns. The text should concatenated, separated by a space (the order of the text being combined doesn't matter). I only care about these three columns.

Table 1:

| Issue | User | Text | other_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | asdf | blah |
| 2 | User2 | qwer | blah |
| 2 | User2 | zxcv | blah |

Table 2:

| Issue | User | Text | other_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | 1234 | blah |
| 2 | User2 | 5678 | blah |
| 2 | User2 | 7890 | blah |
| 3 | User3 | 6845 | blah |

Resulting table:

| Issue | User | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | asdf 1234 |
| 2 | User2 | qwer zxcv 5678 7890 |
| 3 | User3 | 6845 |

This is my code so far. I tried using Group_concat(table1.Text), Group_concat(table1.Text, table2.text), and table1.TEXT (each separately) in the SELECT line but they don't give the desired results.

```
SELECT table1.Issue, table1.User
FROM table1 join table2
ON table1.Issue = table2.Issue and table1.User = table2.User
GROUP BY Issue, User
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have two tables?

Comment: And why isn't it `zxcv qwer 7890 5678`

Comment: @Strawberry the two table's data is from different sources. So, now I'm trying to combine them based on Issue, User, and Text

Comment: @Strawberry it can be, I don't care about the order of the combined text, as long the text are combined and separated by a space

Answer (score 0):

You could try using subquery with group_concat() for aggregate  by common issue and user, using the concat for the result

```
select t1.issue, t1.user, concat(t1.`text`, ' ',t2.text) `text`
from (
    select a.issue, a.user, group_concat(a.`text` separator ' ') `text`
    from table1 a 
    group by a.issue, a.user
) t1 
inner join (
    select b.issue, b.user, group_concat(b.`text` separator) `text`
    from table2 b
    group by b.issue, b.user

    ) t2 on t1.issue = t2.issue, t1.user = t2.user
```

and for the new set of data you should use  a main table derived by subquery for the union  of issue and user

```
select t3.issue, t3.user, concat(t1.`text`, ' ',t2.text) `text`
from (
    select issue, user
    from table1
    union 
    select issue, user
    from table2 
)left JOIN (
    select a.issue, a.user, group_concat(a.`text` separator ' ') `text`
    from table1 a 
    group by a.issue, a.user
) t1  ON t1.issue = t3.issue, t1.user = t3user
left  join (
    select b.issue, b.user, group_concat(b.`text` separator) `text`
    from table2 b
    group by b.issue, b.user

    ) t2 on t31.issue = t2.issue, t3.user = t2.user
```

Comment: Why are you joining tables?

Comment: because are aggreagted .. @Strawberry  .

Comment: thanks for the reply! Sorry, I added another row to the example tables in the main post of edge where if one row only exists in one table, but I still want that row to be in the output. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I get an error with "?" on mysql workbench 8 saying how it's not valid at that position, do you know about this?

Comment: ANSwer  updated  with a suggestion for you new data sample

Answer (score 0):

You have to``CONCAT`both`GROUP_CONCAT` for the the two tables.

To have no cross joins you need to put in aLso a `DISTINCT`into the 'GROUP_CONCAT'

The single Group Concat can be ordered, but the hole Text , you will have to use another way.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `Issue` INTEGER,
  `User` VARCHAR(5),
  `Text` VARCHAR(4),
  `other_column` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`Issue`, `User`, `Text`, `other_column`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'User1', 'asdf', 'blah'),
  ('2', 'User2', 'qwer', 'blah'),
  ('2', 'User2', 'zxcv', 'blah');

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  `Issue` INTEGER,
  `User` VARCHAR(5),
  `Text` INTEGER,
  `other_column` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO table2
  (`Issue`, `User`, `Text`, `other_column`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'User1', '1234', 'blah'),
  ('2', 'User2', '5678', 'blah'),
  ('2', 'User2', '7890', 'blah');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
t1.Issue, t1.User
,CONCat (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTiNCT t1.`Text`),','
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.`Text`)) as 'Text'
FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2
ON t1.Issue = t2.Issue and t1.User = t2.User
GROUP BY t1.Issue, t1.User;
```

| Issue | User | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | asdf,1234 |
| 2 | User2 | qwer,zxcv,5678,7890 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aVc9AgErg7NtRnBzPDdnPt/4)

Like i said in the comments for that you need to simulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `Issue` INTEGER,
  `User` VARCHAR(5),
  `Text` VARCHAR(4),
  `other_column` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`Issue`, `User`, `Text`, `other_column`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'User1', 'asdf', 'blah'),
  ('2', 'User2', 'qwer', 'blah'),
  ('2', 'User2', 'zxcv', 'blah');

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  `Issue` INTEGER,
  `User` VARCHAR(5),
  `Text` INTEGER,
  `other_column` VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO table2
  (`Issue`, `User`, `Text`, `other_column`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'User1', '1234', 'blah'),
  ('2', 'User2', '5678', 'blah'),
  ('2', 'User2', '7890', 'blah'),
  ('3', 'User3',    '6845',     'blah');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
(SELECT 
t1.Issue, t1.User
,IF(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.`Text`) IS NULL,(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTiNCT t2.`Text`)),
CONCat (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.`Text`),','
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTiNCT t2.`Text`) )        
) as 'Text'
FROM table1 t1 LEFT join table2 t2
ON t1.Issue = t2.Issue and t1.User = t2.User
GROUP BY t1.Issue, t1.User)
              UNION 
              (SELECT 
t1.Issue, t1.User
,IF(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.`Text`) IS NULL,(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTiNCT t1.`Text`)),
CONCat (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.`Text`),','
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTiNCT t1.`Text`) )        
) as 'Text'
FROM table2 t1 left join table1 t2
ON t1.Issue = t2.Issue and t1.User = t2.User
             GROUP BY t1.Issue, t1.User);
```

| Issue | User | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | asdf,1234 |
| 2 | User2 | qwer,zxcv,5678,7890 |
| 3 | User3 | 6845 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aVc9AgErg7NtRnBzPDdnPt/6)

Comment: thanks for the reply! Sorry, I added another row to the example tables in the main post of edge where if one row only exists in one table, but I still want that row to be in the output. Thanks!

Comment: mysql doesn't support full outer joins. So to catch all rows, you have to unio a left and right join

Comment: There is nothing to indicate that a join is appropriate here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes you are, you have always to join as you can see in my answer as in the other